# JS to work inside a textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have no experience with using JS to work inside a textarea. I know it's doable as I've seen it.

Links anyone?

Comment: Can you give an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: ...or an example site you're using for inspiration?

Comment: I need information regarding api to accessing textarea data. Like cursor location, text selection, etc. I've seen this stuff done but need a doc to look at. It is surprisingly difficult to Google this due to the amount of non-relevant results.

Comment: There is no "API" as such, just a heap of functions, tricks and workarounds, some of which work cross-browser. I think you need to specify what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Pekka, exactly. Where is a list of those functions, etc? I just recently discovered setSelectionRange which was helpful for cursor positioning. I have tried googling this stuff but finding valid results is very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for starters:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp